# In Angular 6 how make case insensitive url pattern?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

In my case I want to support same url in case insensitive manner.

Example: it should support all url

```
localhost:1029/documentation
localhost:1029/DOCUMENTATION
localhost:1029/DOCUMENTAtion
localhost:1029/docuMENTATION
```

Comment: You mean you want to make those URLs case sensitive? Because they are insensitive by default.

Comment: @ChrisK no, Angular routing is case sensitive

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should add this provide statement to the app.module.ts

```js
    import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
    
    export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
        parse(url: string): UrlTree {
            // Optional Step: Do some stuff with the url if needed.
    
            // If you lower it in the optional step 
            // you don't need to use "toLowerCase" 
            // when you pass it down to the next function
            return super.parse(url.toLowerCase()); 
        }
    }
```

And

```js
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
          ...
        ],
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: UrlSerializer,
                useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
            }
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

Comment: In this case url structure converting lower case.But I want it will be retain same structure what user will give.

Comment: This also changes the query values to lower case which is problematic, the query string values are usually case sensitive

Comment: Worked like a champ, only issue I had was a weirdness of the builder.  "Class '....' used before declaration.", not sure why considering I have it included at the top of the page, so I just renamed the file to save myself the frustration.

Comment: Just FYI, if you use this then your query values will be lower case, which means callbacks with JWT tokens etc will fail

Comment: As @Cesar has already mentioned, this affects query string values. For me specifically, this corrupted how password reset and email confirmation tokens because they got corrupted when lower cased.

Comment: Answer is almost similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39560520/5043867

Comment: This does exactly the opposite to want the OP requires. He wants to maintain case insensitivity.

Answer (score 4):

You need a UrlSerializer as follow:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';


 export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
   parse(url: string): UrlTree {
      return super.parse(url.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

And then added it as a provider in the app.module.ts

```
providers: [
 {
   provide: UrlSerializer,
   useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
}
]
```

Comment: In this case url structure changed to the  lower case.But I want it will be retain same url what user will give.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by this thread, the following variant is supposed to lower-case only the UrlSegments in the URL part - and leave the query params alone.

The idea is to let DefaultUrlSerializer parse the URL to an UrlTree - and then go through the UrlTree and lowercase segments.

```
export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        const urlTree = super.parse(url);

        this.lowerCaseSegments(urlTree.root);

        return urlTree;
    }
    private lowerCaseSegments(urlSegmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup) {
        if (urlSegmentGroup.hasChildren()) {
            Object.entries(urlSegmentGroup.children).forEach(
                ([key, value]) => this.lowerCaseSegments(value)
            );
        }

        urlSegmentGroup.segments.forEach((segment) => segment.path = segment.path.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work, configure the route to NotFoundComponent with wild character like below

```
{path:'**',component:NotFoundComponent}
```

then,
in the NotFoundComponent.ts file, add the below lines inside ngOnInit()

```
if(this.route.snapshot.url[0].path.toLowerCase()!==this.route.snapshot.url[0].path)
      this.router.navigate([this.route.snapshot.url[0].path.toLowerCase()]);
```

You have to import ActivatedRoute,Router from '@angular/router' and inject in constructor like below

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private router:Router) { }
```

Here if condition in ngOnInit() makes sure that it won't route or navigate infinitely

Comment: Again this is the same case, all the query params and route will gets converted into lowercase which is not required as per OP

Comment: You can just convert the URL like this

`let url = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path.split('?')[0];
let query = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path.split('?')[1];
if(url.toLowerCase()!==url){
 this.router.navigate([url.toLowerCase()+'?'+query]);`
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { pascalize } from 'humps';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    override parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        var urlArray = url.split('/');
        urlArray[urlArray.length - 1] = pascalize(urlArray[urlArray.length - 1]);

        var newUrl = urlArray.join('/');
        return super.parse(newUrl);
    }
}
```

I did this because my routes are PascalCased. As long as you have predictable url where your route name is easily found, this strategy would work.

This will take

http://localhost:4200/#/someId/someRoute
and make it
http://localhost:4200/#/someId/SomeRoute