# How to stop Angular forcing query string to lower case

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have an encrypted value in a query string that is case sensitive. When the Angular application loads with the query string, the entire string is forced to become lower case with is breaking other functionality.

Example:
https://someurl.com/en/login?gc%2fGrT4gYjwyLDAWa8raCZ4A0dvzaC0aAZDWnrIYrMdlXiaBnHFPRx0DsQ4PljFWli8Bk19Xfbs586KuXs6fVlqaJvuuuBYf1EKoDJaPeszjJ88S3kMHXtfeMM2KOzk2Gik5exWybASKhhgWK8MKKHefbfWPVLq7

After application loads the this query string becomes:
https://someurl.com/en/login?gc%2fgrt4gyjwyldawa8racz4a0dvzac0aazdwnriyrmdlxiabnhfprx0dsq4pljfwli8bk19xfbs586kuxs6fvlqajvuuubyf1ekodjapeszjj88s3kmhxtfemm2kozk2gik5exwybaskhhgwk8mkkhefbfwpvlq7=

I need the to somehow keep the case sensitive query string intact.

Comment: how are to you creating this query string?

Comment: This is a complete guess but I would assume this behavior is not standard. You probably have something specifically changing it. Do you have custom routing logic or anything on the application?

Comment: Give us more information, code, configurations. Is every URL converted to lowercase (-> webserver config). Is it only in your app (-> need code belonging the request handling)

Comment: How is this Angular application being served?

Comment: Possible duplicate, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985973/in-angular-6-how-make-case-insensitive-url-pattern