# Error entering the URL in Angular minuscule 4,6,7

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem when entering or pasting the url in the lower case of my application.

If I write or paste the url in this way:

```
http://localhost:4200/Customers/Natural
```

Works correctly

but if I enter or paste it in this way

```
http://localhost:4200/clients/natives
I get the error as if the ulr did not exist
```

I am directing with router in angular 7, I can do something so that it does not matter how come the url I work the income?

Urls are declared in this way

[declared  url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIuHs.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Angular 6 how make case insensitive url pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985973/in-angular-6-how-make-case-insensitive-url-pattern)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, before asking for a question, google for it to avoid duplicate questions.

Comment: It does not work, since that code what it does is to convert the url to lowercase, when I need it to be small or camelcase or uppercase work, I can not declare the variables in lowercase at the request of my company

Comment: So you will need to modify the proposed UrlSerializer to turn each piece of the url to CamelCase. But the answer is there.

Comment: There are variables that can reach this form.  `Utilidades/CrearNotificaciones`
since the url variables are declared as `{ path: 'Ahorros/Disponible/TarjetaHabientes', component: TarjetaHabientesComponent }, { path: 'Clientes/Naturales/SolicitudServicios', component: SolicitudServiciosComponent },{ path: 'utilidades/crearnotificaciones', redirectTo: 'Utilidades/CrearNotificaciones' },`


It generates a page error not found