# Angular - How make case insensitive url without changing the URL?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

In my Angular application, I want to support all url's in case insensitive manner and also don't want to change the route name to lowercase.

Example: it should support all URL's along with **Query Parameters**

```
localhost:1029/aboutus
localhost:1029/aboutUS
localhost:1029/AboutUs
localhost:1029/ABOUTUS
```

I have checked this question and many like this but problem is they change URL into lowercase and navigate, I want to navigate but without changing the URL.

[In Angular 6 how make case insensitive url pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985973/in-angular-6-how-make-case-insensitive-url-pattern)

Comment: Interesting!!!!

Comment: Have you checked `regex matchers` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36154766/5107490

Comment: @ShayD yes read the answer earlier but find out not working