# Get ID from API

Tags: angular

I have an API url like this : localhost:3000/api/categories?id=1.
How can i get id in value by query params and delete this Object in Angular 5. My code in angular like this :

```
    private url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/categories';
    deleteMovie(categoryId: number): Observable<CategoriesModel> {    
    const url = url to get value
    return this.http.delete<CategoriesModel>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
     tap(_ => console.log(`Deleted category with id = ${categoryId}`)),
    catchError(error => of(null))
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Gotchas) to obtain ID from string URL:

```js
var paramsStringURL = new URL("http://localhost:3000/api/categories?id=1");
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsStringURL.search);

console.log(searchParams.get("id"));
```

For Angular way fetching from actual URL: [Angular 2 Check if query parameter exists in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41562267/11328122)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import 'ActivatedRoute' :

```
 import {ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
```

and then subscribe to the queryParams like this:

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      let url = params['id'];
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry. can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `categoryId` as `HttpParams`, you can do it like this. I see you are using a variable for the options, so add the `HttpParams` to that, like:

```ts
private url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/categories';

deleteMovie(categoryId: number): Observable<CategoriesModel> {   
  // create params, create a string from the number, since params accepts only string
  const params = new HttpParams().set('id', categoryId.toString());

  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      // ...
    }),
    params: params // add this
  }
  return this.http.delete<CategoriesModel>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log(`Deleted category with id = ${categoryId}`)),
    catchError(error => of(null))
  );
}
```

With the `HttpParams` you will get the desired url: `localhost:3000/api/categories?id=1`